# send() method not working right?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5.2, I'm using send() method to return [] only from construct:
In the same controller:

```
public function __construct() {
   return response()->json()->send();
}
public function index() {
       return 22;
    }
```

But actually, when call function index, I get []22;

How can I fix this, or another method can do that?

Comment: The constructor shouldn't send a response to the browser. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Constructors can't return a value they serve only to instantiate a class

Comment: So what is it you are trying to do exactly. If we knew that, we might be able to offer a solution. The way you've currently explained things leaves me at a loss for words

Comment: It meaning before reach the code of index function, I have to check something such as auth, permission. if not appropriate, return immediately (not touch the code of index  function). btw, I had used beforeFilter function in Laravel 5.1, it working fine

Comment: try using Middleware